# Perform segue in other UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having a problem with a perform segue action. I'm using the InstructionView for setting the objects and call it in the PageViewController class to create new viewController.

Where can I set the action, with the perform segue. If I do it in the InstructionView it crashes. I did embed it as NavigationController.
I think I should make a delegate method, but I don't know how in this context.

**See my code below:**

```
    protocol InstructionViewDelegate
    {
    func didTapLabel(myString: NSString)  
    }  

    class InstructionView: UIViewController
    {
    var delegate : InstructionViewDelegate!
    var pageIndex : Int = 0
    var titleText : String = ""
    var otherImageFile : String = ""

    var tapLabel = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
    ....

    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(16, 825, 736, 104))
    ....
    view.addSubview(label)

    var imageViewObject : UIImageView
    ....
    view.addSubview(imageViewObject)

    tapLabel = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageLabelAction:")
    tapLabel.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tapLabel)
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imageViewObject.addGestureRecognizer(tapLabel)
    imageViewObject.userInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    func imageLabelAction(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    delegate.didTapLabel("The image was tapped")
    }
```

*PageViewController:*

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, InstructionViewDelegate
{
var pageViewController : UIPageViewController?
var pageTitles : Array<String> = ["", "", ""]
var otherImages : Array<String> = ["", "", ""]
var currentIndex : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    pageViewController!.dataSource = self

    let startingViewController: InstructionView = viewControllerAtIndex(0)!
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
    pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    pageViewController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);

    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
    func didTapLabel(myString: NSString) {
    println(myString)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("testSegue", sender: self)
    }


.....

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> InstructionView?
{
    if self.pageTitles.count == 0 || index >= self.pageTitles.count{
        return nil
    }

    let pageContentViewController = InstructionView()
    pageContentViewController.otherImageFile = otherImages[index]
    pageContentViewController.titleText = pageTitles[index]
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    pageContentViewController.delegate = self
    currentIndex = index

    return pageContentViewController
}
}
```

Comment: Please can you clarify your question?  Are you hoping to find out how and where to implement the `imageLabelAction:` method to perform a segue to a new ViewController?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I've tried to do it with an delegate, but it will give me a nill value. I'm still new to Swift.

Comment: And the segue is set up in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I've used a storyboard segue from the PageViewController to a new TestViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think a delegate is probably the best route.  In your `InstructionView` Swift file, define a protocol which will describe the communication from InstructionView to its delegate:

```
protocol InstructionViewDelegate {
    func didTapLabel(myString : String)
}
```

I've assumed you are passing a string value back from InstructionView to the delegate; amend this to reflect the data you actually want to pass.  Add a `delegate` var  to the `InstructionView`:

```
var delegate : InstructionViewDelegate!
```

Also add an `imageLabelAction` function, along these lines:

```
func imageLabelAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // perform any actions here in response to the label being tapped, and finish with:
    delegate.didTapLabel("The image label was tapped")
    // (amend the argument to what you need to send to your TestViewController)
}
```

Amend the class definition for `PageViewController` to indicate that it adopts the InstructionViewDelegate protocol:

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, InstructionViewDelegate {
```

Remember to set the delegate of the InstructionView to point back to self:

```
startingViewController.delegate = self
```

and then implement the function defined by the protocol:

```
func didTapLabel(myString: String) {
    println(myString)
    // do any processing here (e.g. save myString to a local var)
    // before triggering the segue:
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("FromPageVCtoTestVC", sender: self)
}
```

You can then use `prepareForSegue` to pass the relevant data to the destination view controller in the usual way.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation pbasdf, and sorry for the late reaction. I've tried to run the code now but the thing is that I get no segue with identifier: reason: 'Receiver (<NewVisioApp.InstructionView: 0x787773d0>) has no segue with identifier 'testSegue''
See the updated code.
Ps: I don't want to pass data for right now.

Comment: You don't need this line:     `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("testSegue", sender: self)` in the `imageLabelAction` function (because the `didTapLabel` function in `PageViewController` will perform the segue instead).

Comment: I still get an nill value, `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The code stops at the `      delegate.didTapLabel("The image was tapped")` protocol func. I've made some other exercise projects with delegates, and they work fine. I Think the case here is that I make a new ViewController in PageViewController and it won't take the delegate within in.

Comment: found the solution. I just had to declare the delegate to it self when a new pageContentViewController is created. See code. Thanks!